# what is the use of wysiwygAdapter at frontend in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have just checked

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nonamespaceschemalocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referencecontainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Ui\Block\Wysiwyg\ActiveEditor" name="theme.active.editor" template="Magento_Ui::wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml">
            </block>
        </referencecontainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

which initialize wysiwygAdapter at front-end. so what is the use of this code on front-end?
Anyone know?